# What does this code printing addresses on the stack mean?

Tags: variables, rust, memory-address

I did this trying to understand addresses in Rust. It was part of a more complicated experiment. But
first, I'd like to understand this.

```
fn main () {    
    let mut b = 3;
    println!("in main i32        {:p}", &b);
    println!("in main i32        {:p}", &&b);
    println!("in main i32        {:p}", &&&b);
    println!("in main i32        {:p}", &&&&b);
    println!("in main i32        {:p}", &&&&&b);
}
```

I expected a compiler error on all but the first `println!`. But it compiled and ran.
I got a different address
for each call.

Comment: after 8 years of rust I can safely say it's completely useless to know that. Here more https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a805340a93261d8185cd1013d8cbdae3

Comment: Close to useless, I agree. But I should be able to predict what will happen in a short program like this. Thanks for your playground---not sure I could have predicted those outcomes yet either.

Comment: I did learn something about &b being the same, but each &&b being different. Any more explanation on that? I think I get it.

Comment: Note that while `println` does behave differently, nearly any time you use a `&&T`, it will either be automatically dereferenced or optimized out. That is why this is useless.

Comment: what do you want to predict ? you create temporary variable and ask for its address so rust show an address, the rest is implementation behavior.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `&` operator in `Rust` to take a reference to a value, it creates a new reference that points to the memory location of the original value. Each additional `&` creates a new reference to the previous reference. In your example, when you use multiple `&` operators, you are creating references to references. The addresses printed by each `println!` statement correspond to the memory locations of these references.

So, `&b` takes a reference to the value of `b`, consequently `&&b` takes a referene to the value of `&b` and so forth.

Comment: So I am *creating* new references  inside the println!. Is that right?  5 months into Rust and I still can write 10 line programs and not be able to predict the outcome. Each time though, I narrow that space.

Comment: Note that there is nothing specific about `println!` in this case. What you are doing is equivalent to `let tmp1 = &b; let tmp2 = &tmp1; let tmp3 = &tmp2;` and so on, which is how those references get created.

Comment: @PaulCommentary The `println!` macro is not directly responsible for creating the references. Instead, it's the multiple `&` operators in your code that create new references. In each line, the `&` operator is used to take the reference of the previous reference. The `println!` macro simply receives these expressions as arguments and evaluates them, printing the memory addresses of the resulting references.

Comment: Agreed. I think I wrote creating new reference inside the println!. Maybe better would be inside the call to println!.